# Batch scala API post requests

Tags: scala, log4j

I am implementing a custom log4j appender in scala that sends log messages to elastic search API end point. Here is the code,

```
class KibanaAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

override def append(event: LoggingEvent): Unit = {
val finalMessage =
      s"""|{"create": {"_index" : "$indexName"}}
          |{"message":"$message","level":"$level","@timestamp":"$timeStamp"
    """.stripMargin

HttpService.post(json = finalMessage)
}

override def close(): Unit = {
    if (!this.closed) {
      this.closed = true
    }
  }

  override def requiresLayout(): Boolean = true
}
```

As the API end point supports bulk requests, is there a way these requests can be batched with defined batch size and post them?

Answer (score 0):

Batching `LogEvent`s for performance is a pretty common practice in almost every Log4j appender. You can check out the sources for inspiration. This said, I am curious why do you implement your own appender for such a simple job. A combination of HTTP or Socket appenders with JSON Template Layout should be more than enough to feed logs into Elasticsearch. You don't really need to write a single line of code.